# Exception when using Rasteredge.Imaging.ORC recognition image

Tags: image-processing, emgucv

I use *Dll Rasteredge.Imaging.ORC* and I have exception *"ORCRuntimeException was unhandled"* Resource dictionary preparation failed. Links http://www.rasteredge.com/

```
Bitmap default_image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
RasterEdge.Imaging.Basic.Core.REImage img = new RasterEdge.Imaging.Basic.Core.REImage(default_image);            RasterEdge.Imaging.OCR.OCRHandler.SetTrainResourcePath(@"C:\Source");

img = img.Resize(new Size((int)img.Width * 2, (int)img.Height*2));
RasterEdge.Imaging.OCR.OCRPage page1 = RasterEdge.Imaging.OCR.OCRHandler.Import(img);      
page1.Recognize();
```

What is the problem here and how to make it working?

Answer (score 1):

hi I found the solution for this problem.

the main problem is in **RasterEdge.Imaging.OCR.OCRHandler.SetTrainResourcePath(@"C:\Source");**

you have to change the path C:\source to Source if you copy eng.traineddata file to the bin file of your project or you can copy it to the same directory at C HDD inside folder Source.